# ODATA, JSON and Python

Tags: python, odata

I am stuck on this problem I would like to request this URL, which is in a `odata` format

```
"http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json"
```

and that comes from this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/leohu/2013/10/04/odata-and-json-payload-examples/). I tried with the following code but it doesn't work

```py
from odata import ODataService

url_test = "http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products?
    $format=json"

service = ODataService(url, reflect_entities=False)

service.entities['ID']
```

My end goal is to retrieve all the different ID with their Price.

Thanks

I have this error message

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2db727483d6e> in <module>()
      3 service
      4 
----> 5 service.entities['ID']

KeyError: 'ID'
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not really know the module `OData`. It seems to be deprecated, abandoned or similar as you could see on the Pypi repository ([link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/OData/0.0.0)). Anyways, have you tried retrieving the data using `requests`?

```
import requests

url_test = 'http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json'

r = requests.get(url_test)

r_json = r.json()
for value in r_json['value']:
    print(value['ID'])
```

This seems to work for me.

Comment: OData is not deprecated. You can find more information at: http://odata.org
The .Net implementation of OData can be found at: http://github.com/odata

Comment: I was only refering to the Python module placed on Pypi. Thanks for the information anyhow :)

Comment: It is avaialble for python clients -- https://github.com/SAP/python-pyodata or

Answer (score 3):

The library OData library used in the question doesn't exist anymore. Anyone wondering how to work with OData in Python can check this out: [python-pyodata](https://pyodata.readthedocs.io/)

Using this library you can make a request like this:

```py
import requests
import pyodata

SERVICE_URL = 'http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/'

# Create instance of OData client
client = pyodata.Client(SERVICE_URL, requests.Session())
```

You can checkout the documentation to see how to use it: https://github.com/SAP/python-pyodata/blob/master/docs/usage/README.md

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Hussain Their documentation suggests they only support Odata V2, do you know of any currently maintained python clients that have good support for V4?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but there's a branch for v3 and v4. You can check those out:
v4: https://github.com/SAP/python-pyodata/tree/wip-odata-v4
v3: https://github.com/SAP/python-pyodata/tree/experimental_v3